# Need to reload page when request sent for invalidated session

Tags: javascript, java, session, session-cookies

I need to reload page when request sent for a session that is no longer valid

Comment: Java? You wrote JavaScript, not java. Tell us more about the Web server.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with Java. You need to get your drag-and-drop sorted out in Javascript, and once you have a file, whether it's dragged-and-dropped or anything else, you need to send it to the server using the appropriate method and mime type, and read it accordingly on the server side.